# Property or indexer of type RepeatedField cannot be assigned to — it is read only

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I am new to Google ProtoBuf file. I have below message in a ProtoBuf file.

```
 message AvailabilityOfLockersResp{
  uint32 NumberOfAvailableLockers;
  repeated uint32 lockerIds = 1;
 }
```

I have generated the corresponding ProtoBuf C# class using `protoc.exe` and added that generated C# class file inside my .NET project file.

When I assign a value to the generated `LockerIds` field I get the error "Property or indexer 'AvailabilityOfLockersResp.LockerIds' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only":

[image: screenshot of the error as shown in Visual Studio]

It is showing me that it's a read-only field. But, I want to assign a value to this field. How can I add things to this field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question I asked above.

```
        List<uint> lockerIds = new List<uint>();

        ProtoPacket protoPacketResponse = new ProtoPacket 
        {               
            AvailabilityOfLockersResp = new AvailabilityOfLockersResp { NumberOfAvailableLockers = (uint)lockerIds.Count() }//LockerIds = lockerIds,
        };
```

Outside of new instance, I have assigned the value to the ***LockerIds*** like below,

```
protoPacketResponse.AvailabilityOfLockersResp.LockerIds.AddRange(lockerIds);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AvailabilityOfLockersResp avail = new AvailabilityOfLockersResp();
avail.LockerIds.AddRange(new List<int>{1,2,3});
```